# Generating incremental number with YYMM1234 LIKE format when inserting data in database

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to Generate autoincremental number with YYMM1234 LIKE format when inserting data in database using laravel

Comment: How is the structure of the table you want to generare the number from?
And what is YYMM? Is it the year and month for today?

Comment: Yes YYMM is first 2 number and 2number of month

Answer (score 0):

First define id column with auto increment option in your table.
Then set custom auto increment id column nullable .
In laravel, save your record with auto increment null value.

```
$rec->otherVariables = ...;
$rec->otherVariables2=...;
$rec->save();
```

Again, save your custom increment using the below code

```
$rec->custom_auto_increment_col = Carbon::now()->format('ym').$rec->id;
$rec->save()
```

I hope, it will satisfy your needs.